Pulled one side of a curtain off the wall, how to fix it up?
I was opening the blinds in a dark room when the rod pulled on the curtain and caused on side of it to come off the wall. It was held by two screws and expanders. I truly did not apply much force, stopped when felt resistance, and no wall material has come off the wall, as if the hole drilled was a little too big. As you can see the expander is not damaged, nor really 'expanded'. How can I fix this without a drill? I can go to a hardware shop for filler and expanders by the way. 

Did the head of the top screw pull right through the hole in the bracket, or did you push/screw it back in there?

Good question, I pushed it back, the head is not too small.

It looks as if the screws used were too small.
You need to remove the old screws and replace them with larger screws,( width or thickness, not length.)
The larger screws will grip the wall anchors (expanders) and be better at securing the rod holder to the wall.
The whole process will be easier if you release the screw at the rear of the holder and remove it from the rod. Then reinstall the rod when the holder is anchored properly.

Well, also looks like the anchors aren't strong enough.

Thanks @RMDman, indeed I removed everything in the holes: screws and expanders and went for new ones, a little bit larger. Had to cut an outstanding bit of expanding with a blunt kitchen knife, but totally worth it! It's all tight now! Thanks for the help!
